# Sparse Eigenvectors for the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix

Tags: fourier-analysis, reference-request, eigenvector, sparse-matrices

There are many ways to choose eigenbasis for the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix since it has only $4$ distinct eigenvalues taken from $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

Has there been any refereed work that provides a sparse eigenvector basis for the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix?

Comment: FYI, I addressed this question in a *non-refereed* article available on ArXiv: [Sparse Eigenvectors of the Discrete Fourier Transform](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2922).